Can we revers the process of plastics to fuel
I am a 10th grade student who is trying to convert plastics into fuel.
My question is that when we can make plastic from oil/fuel then can we revers the process?
But we should be able to revers the process efficiently and it should be economically feasible.If you have any suggestions please let me know.

When you state "oil/fuel" you presumably mean conversion of a raw petroleum feedstock into polymer precursors, and those precursors into polymers. The path that takes you to polymer precursors at some point diverges from that which takes you to the fuels you use in vehicles or even heating/electric power generation. And once you get to polymers you might not want to go back to fuels. The regenerated feedstock (or whatever you generate in attempting to reverse polymerization) might be valuable for applications other than energy generation.

See this: https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abh0626

Plastics are already a fuel that can be burnt, but there's plenty of other ways to deal with them. You don't seem to know first thing about depolymeristion, cracking, etc., though, so your q. appears to violate our homework policy.

But then why not make them into paints. It will work as a waterproofing also.
